# My popups are at bottom:0; but after you hover over them 2-3 times they keep going up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[My blog](http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com) has these popups, and they are at bottom 0. But when you hover over them twice or more times they begin to go up farther each time you hover. Any way to prevent?

Edit: The reason it's doing this is because each time it hovers, the "bottom" resets so it's going -10px from where it last was. I don't know how to stop this.

Answer: I added info.css("bottom', '-10px'); and that fixed it. Thanks to all who answered, though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the position on rollover? If so, try setting the position at load and just turning the display on/off at mouseover/mouseout.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript, change:

```
bottom: '-=' + distance,
```

to

```
bottom: '+=' + distance,
```

On mouse over you are subtracting -10 pixels to the distance from the bottom. On mouse out, you need to add those -10px.

Sorry for the mix up earlier, I got confused about adding negative numbers.

Comment: That just makes it fade in, it fades up and fades out going up. I can do that by setting var distance = 0

Comment: I initially had it wrong, use the code above, you need add the distance back in.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add `position:absolute` to the style of the popup